# Words count JavaScript - For Loop

Tags: javascript, c, cs50

Updated: I realize that in C I initialized the word counter  1. (I've tried to delete the inquiry but I was not allowed) :/

in order to try to learn to code I signed up for CS50 and on PSET2 there's an exercise called "Readability". I'm trying to recreate the program with JavaScript. According to the instructions provided the output of input should be **55 words** but I'm getting 54.

My *For Loop* is iterating over each element of the array and if it finds a space, it will add 1 to the words counter (my guess is that it is not counting the last word because it ends with a ".") [image: here's a preview of JavaScript Output]

However, my C program code seems to work fine. [image: here's a preview of C Output]

JavaScript Code:

```
let text = "It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen. Winston Smith, his chin nuzzled into his breast in an effort to escape the vile wind, slipped quickly through the glass doors of Victory Mansions, though not quickly enough to prevent a swirl of gritty dust from entering along with him."

let words = 0;
let textArray = Array.from(text);


//Words
for (let i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++){
  if (textArray[i] == " "){
    words ++;
  }
}


console.log("Words: " + words);
```

C Program Code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{
    //Ask user for text
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    
    //define variables
    int letters = 0;
    int words = 1;
    int sentences = 0;
    
    //loop to analyze text
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        //count letters
        if ((text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z') || (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            letters++;
        }
        //count words
        else if (text[i] == ' ')
        {
            words++;
        }
        //count sentences
        else if ((text[i] == '.') || (text[i] == '?') || (text[i] == '!'))
        {
            sentences++;
        }
    }
    
    printf("Words: %i\n", words);
    //math calculation (third rule)
    float l = 100 * ((float) letters / (float) words);
    float s = 100 * ((float) sentences / (float) words); 
    
    //printf("l: %i\n",  (int) round(l));
    //printf("s: %i\n", (int) round(s));
    
    //grade index formula
    float grade = (0.0588 * l) - (0.296 * s) - 15.8;
    if (grade >= 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else if (grade < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", (int) round(grade));
    }
    
   
}
```

Comment: Your code has only `54` spaces. The result is correct.

Comment: Think about how many _spaces_ the sentence `This is a test` has... and how many _words_.

Comment: Thanks for replying, what I don't seem to understand is that it is exactly the same sentence in C, and that code outputs 55 words, any comments on why C is getting a different number than JavaScript with the same input?

Comment: I'm getting [54](https://replit.com/@clapynick/LightgreyNotableQuotes#main.c) with your C code also, not 55

Comment: You can see that you have initialized with words=1

Comment: Yes, my bad!!! thanks for your time and patience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are 4 spaces in a well-formed sentence then there are 5 words. Example:

**"I am a boy" - 3 spaces, 4 words**

The above is a naive generalization but for simple cases this is true.

So you can maybe initialize `words` from 1 instead of 0. This is a very naive solution, but will help as a starting step.

```js
let text = "It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen. Winston Smith, his chin nuzzled into his breast in an effort to escape the vile wind, slipped quickly through the glass doors of Victory Mansions, though not quickly enough to prevent a swirl of gritty dust from entering along with him."

let words = 1;
let textArray = Array.from(text);


//Words
for (let i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++){
  if (textArray[i] == " "){
    words ++;
  }
}


console.log("Words: " + words);
```

**EDIT**
: Your C code initializes `words` with 1 so that is the offset.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! my question is that it is exactly the same sentence in C, and that code outputs 55 words, any comments on why C is getting a different number than JavaScript with the same input?

Comment: Check how you are initializing in the C code. Maybe add the whole code in question, even better if you provide a link to an online C compiler

Answer (score 1):

If there is a single space in two text then word should be number of `space + 1`

e.g `hello world` so there is only `1` space so number of word will be `2`

```js
let text =
  "It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen. Winston Smith, his chin nuzzled into his breast in an effort to escape the vile wind, slipped quickly through the glass doors of Victory Mansions, though not quickly enough to prevent a swirl of gritty dust from entering along with him.";

const words = Array.from(text).filter((s) => s === " ").length + 1;

console.log("Words: " + words);
```

You can use regex here `/\s+/`

```js
let text =
  "It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen. Winston Smith, his chin nuzzled into his breast in an effort to escape the vile wind, slipped quickly through the glass doors of Victory Mansions, though not quickly enough to prevent a swirl of gritty dust from entering along with him.";

const words = text.split(/\s+/g).length;

console.log("Words: " + words);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm not familiar with regular expressions but I'll make sure to read about them. Any comments on why the way I wrote it skipping one word? (besides that it's probably not the best approach! LoL)

Comment: @Joe Updated code with `filter`

Comment: If you not familiar with regular expressions just use similar apprach without it: text.split(' ').length

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with this answer? Isn't this simple

```js
let text = "It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen. Winston Smith, his chin nuzzled into his breast in an effort to escape the vile wind, slipped quickly through the glass doors of Victory Mansions, though not quickly enough to prevent a swirl of gritty dust from entering along with him."

let words = 0;
// removing special characters and convert to array by space 
let wordCount = text.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').split(" ").length;
console.log(wordCount) // 55
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers are correct, but the point is the initialize.
If the text is empty, the 'words' should be 0.

```
let text = "It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen. Winston Smith, his chin nuzzled into his breast in an effort to escape the vile wind, slipped quickly through the glass doors of Victory Mansions, though not quickly enough to prevent a swirl of gritty dust from entering along with him."

const textArray = Array.from(text);
let words = (textArray.length)? 1 : 0;  // set initial value for words.

textArray.forEach(e => { 
  if (e === " ") words++;
});

console.log("Words: " + words);
```

And you can use this line to change string to array.

```
// const textArray = Array.from(text);
const textArray = [ ...text ];
```